# Is it possible for the value property to be a different data type in a setter method for attribute

Tags: c#

I wish to do this code in the setter, however visual studio says "value" has to be the same data type. Is there any way to do this.

```
public Image projectImage {
    set
    {
        var byteArray = new WebClient().DownloadData(value);
        this.projectImage.Source = ImageSource.FromStream(() => new MemoryStream(byteArray));       
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

[DownloadData documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.webclient.downloaddata?view=netframework-4.8)

As you can see from the documentation the signatures are:

> DownloadData(String)
>
> Downloads the resource as a Byte array from the URI specified.
>
> DownloadData(Uri)
>
> Downloads the resource as a Byte array from the URI specified.

You are giving a type of Image to it so the compiler naturally resists.

What you need to do is to download the image outside of the setter and then assign to it the image if you want to use the value.

You can't pass a string into the setter, if that's what you want to do here.

What you can do, is use a function like this:

```
public bool SetImageFromUrl(string url) {
      var byteArray = new WebClient().DownloadData(url);
      this.projectImage.Source = ImageSource.FromStream(() => new MemoryStream(byteArray));
}

public Image projectImage {get; set; }
```

Comment: I tried this but  I am getting a System.NullReferenceException  on this line "this.projectImage.Source = ImageSource.FromStream(() => new MemoryStream(byteArray));"